# Does Window.DataContext and Window.Resource ObjectDataProvider conflict

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm still getting comfortable with WPF, so this might be a silly question. I'm tracking the source of a tab control issue and discovered that I don't know the answer to the question in the title.

My Mvvm-Lite project template put the usual in the Windows opening tag:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
```

And from somewhere else (I really don't remember) I have this handy static resource:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="src" ObjectType="vm:MainViewModel" />
```

While I'm troubleshooting my tab control issue (I won't bore you with those details here) I realized that I didn't know if these two ways of pointing to the view model confilicted in any way. Two separate instances of the view model? I don't think so cause the ViewModelLocator is holding a static reference to Main. Anyway, I just wanted to be sure that I haven't made a "greenie" mistake.
Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is going to create two different instances. You can easily verify this by placing a breakpoint in the MainViewModel constructor and running your application in debug mode.

ObjectDataProvider was introduced before MVVM was popular. I would argue that many objects in WPF are kind of obsoleted by MVVM, because now we create these objects and properties in code in the ViewModel layer. In your case, I guess that you probably don't need the ObjectDataProvider, but can use the ViewModelLocator.Main everywhere instead.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: You were correct. I was getting two instances of my view model. It turns out that was confusing my tab control. So it fixed that issue for me. Thanks for the help. Also, thanks for the framework.